# WSO2 - API Manager - apictl export an API and import it in another WSO2 API Manager instance

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

For deployment purposes, i would like to export an API will all its API Manager settings and import it in another API Manager instance. I wanted to use apictl based on the documentation, i exported a zip file of one of my APIs and then i created a new instance of API Manager where i added it as a new environment under apictl. Then i logged in to this new env and i ran the following import command: apictl import api -f dev/exportedAPI1.zip -e dev2

I got this result:

```
Error importing API. Status: 404 Response: <html>

<head>

 </head>

 <body>
   <h2>Error 404 : Resource cannot be found.</h2>

   <br/>

   <p>


   <h4>The resource you are looking for might have been removed,had its name changed, is temporarily unavailable or does not exist. </h4>



  </body>
</html>
apictl: Error importing API Reason: 404
Exit status 1
```

With verbose:

```
[INFO]: Deleting C:\Users\USERR\AppData\Local\Temp\project- 
  artifact715040886.zip
[ERROR]: remove C:\Users\USERR\AppData\Local\Temp\project- 
 artifact715040886.zip: The process cannot access the file because 
 it 
is being used by another process.
[INFO]: Deleting 
C:\Users\USERR\AppData\Local\Temp\apim553052960\accounts-1.0
apictl: Error importing API Reason: 404
Exit status 1
```

Comment: What is the APIM version and apictl version you are using ?

Comment: 4.2.0 Latest version

Answer (score 0):

I just tried out the same scenario and didn't get any issues. Make sure you provide the correct path of the exported API zip file

```
apictl import api -f <path-to-API-archive> -e <environment>
```

However, I'm on Linux. I hope you are on Windows, when looking at the file path. I found a common solution[1] to fix issues like the one above. If you are still experiencing problems even after entering the correct command with the correct path, you can try that solution

[1] https://knowledge.hubspot.com/settings/sales-windows-tray-app-install-error-process-cannot-access-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process